# Make TestCafe show an object diff

Tags: javascript, assert, e2e-testing, testcafe, end-to-end

We're using TestCafe for end-to-end testing, and I'm finding myself looking at an error like this:

```
AssertionError: expected [ Array(5) ] to deeply equal [ Array(5) ]
```

I'd like error messages like this to include a diff. I know object diffing modules are available on npm, but I'd like to add it in such a way that I don't have to import this library any time I'm asserting object equality.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a very similar typescript function which involves a bread first search through all properties of an object. I slightly modified it for your purpose. Maybe it would work. I didn't tested it.

```
isPrimitiveType(o) {
  const t = typeof o;
  return t == 'string' || t == 'number' || t == 'boolean';
}

printDiff(obj: any, userPref: any) {
    if (obj === undefined || obj === null) {
      return;
    }
    for (let k in obj) {
      let prop = obj[k];
      if (isPrimitiveType(prop)) {
        if (!userPref[k]) {
          console.log(userPref[k], ' not matches');
        } 
      } else {
        if (!userPref[k]) {
          console.log(userPref[k], ' not matches');
        } else {
          this.setUserPrefs(obj[k], userPref[k]);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice function! But how would I set this up with TestCafe?

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about TestCafe, sorry

Answer (score 1):

The latest TestCafe version (`1.11.0`) shows the object differences.
[image: object differences]